# my if statement does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

This JavaScript code is to change the background of a div if the content is different:

```
function myfunction() {
    $a = document.getElementById('t').getElementsByTagName('div');
    var x = 0;
    while(x < $a.length) {
        var b = ($a[x].innerHTML);
        b.toString;
        alert(x + b[x]);
        if(b == 'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER' ||b == 'PENDING APPROVAL BY SCHEME MANAGER' ||b == 'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER' ||b == 'PENDING REVIEW TEAM MEMBER BY LEAD ASSESSOR' ||b == 'PENDING ACKNOWLEDGEMENT BY TA/LA' ||b == 'PENDING PREPARE AUDIT PLAN BY LA' ||b == 'PENDING REVIEW AUDIT PLAN BY AO' ||b == 'PENDING ACCEPT LA BY LAB' ||b == 'PENDING VERIFY REASON BY AO' ||b == 'PENDING CONDUCT ASSESSMENT' || b == 'PENDING CORRECTIVE ACTION BY CAB' || b == 'PENDING REVIEW BY AO' || b == 'PENDING CORRECTIVE ACTION APPROVAL BY SCHEME MANAGER' ||b == 'PENDING APPROVAL BY DOA' ){
            document.getElementById('status'+x).style.background="maroon";
            alert(x + b);
        }
        x++;

    }
}
```

It doesn't work because the `if` statement is failing.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: You're mixing javascript and php

Comment: Since when `$` marks a variable in JS?

Comment: @user1718294 It's still a valid var char.

Comment: When you ask questions here, and say "does not work", please be **specific** about what "does not work" means. We're not mind readers, and we don't always have enough of your code to be able to run it and figure out what problem you're trying to solve. You know when you post what "does not work" means, so spend the time telling us. It will get you help faster.

Comment: `The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in an identifier. The dollar sign is intended for use only in mechanically generated code.`

Comment: There's a number of people that use `$variables` to it's a jQuery variable .

Comment: This code seems wrong in many levels, first it does seem like you're mixing JS and PHP. `$a` is global. `toString` must be a function, and your if statement is _insanely_ long, try breaking it up in smaller parts and you might find your problem.

Comment: @webarto: Where did you get that quote? It's a common practice to prefix variables that contain jQuery objects with dollar signs.

Comment: @Blender http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf Page 17.

Comment: @webarto: I can only find `This standard specifies specific character additions: The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted
anywhere in an IdentifierName.`

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you need to assign `b.toString()` to a new variable.

Comment: Your code [is working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/muyJk/4/).

Comment: @Blender I cannot find a PDF for that, I quoted it from answer on Stackoverflow and now see that mechanical part was removed. Still, it is not jQuery or invalid.

Comment: What do you think that random `b.toString` line does?

Comment: @serenna Please show us the rest of your code.  Your html, to be specific, as it is clear from some basic testing that the above code is not at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a note, `b.toString;` should be `b.toString();`

And personally I prefer using double quotes, but that's just due to being used to strongly type them and having a difference between characters and Strings.

***Saw others say it, but just to emphasize : a variable in a function not having the 'var' keyword makes them global, meaning they are accessible, and changeable in any scope in the program.***

Try using the following javascript code : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkFLc/1/)

Changed the way you set the background colour.

Comment: Don't know where the downvote came from, but a remark is always nice so I can improve my answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried examining the value of `b` to see what it typically contains?

Comment: @serenna Like I already said, [your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/muyJk/4/).

Comment: @Daneo .. Yes, it does.  Click the link and see for yourself before saying otherwise.

Comment: @Daneo Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @Daneo So, in other words, you never clicked my link, but your own.  I already defined that div along with the others for the test case.

Comment: @Daneo That's not the latest version, as I clearly linked in reply to serenna on this answer.

Comment: @Daneo Do you seriously want a screen shot.. It was 9 minutes ago.  The fourth comment to this specific answer.

Comment: @Daneo Not SO's, yours.  Look at the fourth comment _on this answer_, not the second to last _on the question_.

Comment: i think the problem is with my html.

Comment: @serenna Please post your html.

Comment: tq all who helped. i just started learning programming. i'm a noob

Comment: @serenna My pleasure, consider marking this as answered please. Cheers. (Removed comments about Daedalus example)

Comment: Sorry, the downvote was mine, because there was no answer here before (and an irrelevant comment about what quotes to use), a suggestion should not have been an answer. Now you actually have an answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) from `underscore.js`, which would make the `if` a little less complex. Instead, it would look more like:

```
var collection = [
    'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER', 
    'PENDING APPROVAL BY SCHEME MANAGER', 
    'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER', 
    'PENDING REVIEW TEAM MEMBER BY LEAD ASSESSOR', 
    'PENDING ACKNOWLEDGEMENT BY TA/LA', 
    'PENDING PREPARE AUDIT PLAN BY LA', 
    'PENDING REVIEW AUDIT PLAN BY AO', 
    'PENDING ACCEPT LA BY LAB', 
    'PENDING VERIFY REASON BY AO', 
    'PENDING CONDUCT ASSESSMENT', 
    'PENDING CORRECTIVE ACTION BY CAB', 
    'PENDING REVIEW BY AO', 
    'PENDING CORRECTIVE ACTION APPROVAL BY SCHEME MANAGER', 
    'PENDING APPROVAL BY DOA'];

if(_.contains(collection, b)) {
    alert("this condition is true!");
    //...
}
```

If it alerts, it's a problem within the if statement. If not, the condition isn't being met and I'd probably start by looking at leading and trailing whitespace in the HTML.

Comment: Why not `collection.indexOf(b) != -1`?

Comment: I think `_.contains` is a bit more expressive, and readability is generally what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can "test" your if statement by simplifying it (this is a universal debugging technique):

```
var b = 'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER';

if (b == 'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER' || b == 'PENDING APPROVAL BY SCHEME MANAGER' || b == 'PENDING SELECTING TEAM MEMBER' || b == 'PENDING REVIEW TEAM MEMBER BY LEAD ASSESSOR' || b == 'PENDING ACKNOWLEDGEMENT BY TA/LA' || b == 'PENDING PREPARE AUDIT PLAN BY LA' || b == 'PENDING REVIEW AUDIT PLAN BY AO' || b == 'PENDING ACCEPT LA BY LAB' || b == 'PENDING VERIFY REASON BY AO' || b == 'PENDING CONDUCT ASSESSMENT' || b == 'PENDING CORRECTIVE ACTION BY CAB' || b == 'PENDING REVIEW BY AO' || b == 'PENDING CORRECTIVE ACTION APPROVAL BY SCHEME MANAGER' || b == 'PENDING APPROVAL BY DOA')
{
    alert("Working");
}
```